# Is reference counting the same as ownership counting?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, reference, automatic-ref-counting

Consider the following statement from "Big Nerd Ranch: Objective-C Programming" - Chapter 21: Object Instance Variables and Properties:

> When an object has an object instance variable, the object with the pointer is said to *own* the object that is being pointed to.

Now consider the following scenario:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int arc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *message = @"Hello, world!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the **message** object has one (1) reference. But... does it have any owner(s)?

If we strictly stick to the cited definition, there is no ***object with a pointer*** referencing this NSString. Does that mean that **message** has one (1) reference but no (0) owners?

And, if that is the case, what does ARC take into account when deciding whether to deallocate an object? Reference count or ownership count?

Comment: Your code example isn't useful because there's no meaningful reference counting, ownership, or deallocation involved. String literals have static lifetime. They exist from process beginning through to its end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference counting is simply a number maintained by the object.

Ownership is a policy, almost a philosophy. It is a way of thinking that tries to ensure that you intervene coherently with an object's reference count.

Comment: And please see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management